# Will flutter changes affect my released application

Tags: flutter, apk, release

Flutter app is updating day by day and lot of things are removed in the new version what will happen if i release and flutter remove a thing that I used in released apk will it affect my app???

Example first firestore.instance was used but not it is not supported it must be firebasefirestore.instance

Comment: While breaking changes do occure from time to time when you update either Futter itself or some dependencies you use, you don't have to always blindly update every update that drops. That being said, no if Flutter or a library updates,  the released apk is not affected whatsoever. The apk has to be rebuilt with the newever updates and re-released.